# Do internship and part time counts when company says certain number of yrs of experience requirments?

Tags: work-experience, qualification, entry-level

I have total of about 2 years of internship and part time job experience. Do these count when companies require a certain number of years of experiences? Also would I still count as entry level or experienced? Thank you.

Comment: Was there an experience? If so it counts

Answer (score 2):

If you've done things as part of a job in a relevant work environment, then yes I would say that counts as experience.

It's also worth applying to jobs anyway if you're not sure you have enough experience or even if you know that you don't have as much experience as they're asking for. (I know several people who have done this and got the job.)

I don't think most people would consider 2 years or less as being very experienced but this may partly depend on your line of work. You're probably not considered entry level anymore but you wouldn't be assumed to be an expert either. I assume that all the jobs you are talking about were in the same field.

Comment: This is my exact problem. I feel like im in that awkward middle where i am not really good enough to be the "expert" yet not really the entry level either... so I dont really seem to belong anywhere :/

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it *too* much. You're past the worst part, which is getting out of the no-experience zone. It just means that you may have to do a bit more convincing than some other, more experienced people in interview. Just out of curiosity what line of work are you in?

Comment: I am in the marketing / graphic design field which makes it even harder for me to find job at this phase since they require a lot of

Comment: Oops i accidently pressed done. But yeah they do require a lot me expertise and don't have much space for entry level unless one is willing to do something sales related which I definitely has no interest in.

Comment: In that case maybe you can make a portfolio to showcase your ability and even do some extra work in your free time to add to it. Basically you need to get the chance to show that though you may have less experience than other candidates you are still capable of producing good quality ideas and results.

Comment: That is good point. I just lack confidence and feel like showing my work will lower my chances even more but I guess I need to get over it and put some more efforts. Thanks for your helpful advice :)

Comment: No problem :) I understand the confidence thing, I struggle with that too sometimes - if you do apply to jobs and are rejected then most people are willing to give feedback afterwards, which you can use to help you the next time. I found that that helps a lot.

Comment: @user27021: if showing your work would lower your chances then it sounds like you need to figure out how to fix that pronto.

Answer (score 1):

"Years of experience" is a proxy for "experience and skill with the tools" (which may include the social tools of handling customers, depending on what the job is). If you've been working part time and the parts add up to the asked-for number of years, you've met that criterion.

If you can't add it up to the required number of years... a portfolio, if your field uses them, can definitely offset that.

It never hurts to submit an honest resume even if you don't meet all the formal requirements. The worst that happens is they throw it out. On the other hand, something in it may catch their eye and makes them think you're worth bringing in... or they may not get any/many applicants more qualified than you and decide they'd better lower the bar.

Don't reject yourself prematurely. That's their job. (grin)

Answer (score 0):

One thing is to prove your skill, another is to show it on paper in terms of experiences. Only Government companies and some others ask for full-time experiences. In IT/ITeS related jobs internships, part-time and full time jobs are taken into account .  But be assured that the companies prefer people with full-time experience over others.